# Cannot connect to TLS 1.2 secured mail box server

Tags: c#, tls1.2

I have a simple C# code that tries to access to a tls secured mail box server using Limilabs email library.

But I get an error about Tls 1.2 :

```
Authenticate as SSL/TLS client failed.
You might be connecting to non SSL/TLS port -or- using incorrect SSL/TLS version.
Consider using TLS 1.2: client.SSLConfiguration.EnabledSslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12;
Please examine the inner exception for details.
```

Yet I use Tls 1.2 in my code before trying to access the secured mail box server :

```
 System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.SystemDefault | SecurityProtocolType.Tls13 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

And I have added those keys in my Windows 10 registry :

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client\Enabled = 0x00000001
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client\DisabledByDefault = 0x00000000
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\SchUseStrongCrypto = 0x00000001
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\SchUseStrongCrypto = 0x00000001
```

Do you have an idea ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Eric.

Comment: So we come to the second part of the errror message: "You might be connecting to non SSL/TLS port". Are you connecting to a non TLS port? We can't tell given the information in your question

Comment: Why did you add those registry settings? It's quite possible you *broke* TLS. Windows 10 supports TLS1.2 out of the box. The *supported* Windows 10 versions come with .NET Framework 4.6.2 at least, which uses TLS1.2 automatically. Which Windows 10 version are you using? If it's an old version *why?* That's what you have to fix. Windows 10 is a service offering  - you *must* let it update itself, as old versions get out of support quickly

Comment: What is the `InnerException`

Comment: @canton7 : I don't think I am connecting to non SSL.TLS port, I try to connect to outlook.office365.com, I think it's TLS 1.2.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos : I use Windows 10 Professional. I don't think I broke TLS because yesterday I have run WireShark and I have seen TLS 1.2 in the packets protocol.

Comment: @Charlieface : the inner exception is :
InnerException: {"Impossible to read data from transport connection : An existing connection has to be closed by remote host."}

Comment: Are you sure the remote server supports TLS 1.2?

Comment: No I'm not sure.
Is there a way to get this information ?
The remote servers are : 
outlook.office365.com 
pop.mail.yahoo.com

Comment: With WireShark, I can see that when the program tries to connect to the remote servers, the protocol is 'DNS' instead of 'TLSv1.2'.
And 'TLSv1.2' appears in other packets which means that  'TLSv1.2' is available and used, but not by my program.

Comment: Sorry, in fact I understood that the protocol is 'DNS' because it resolves the remote server name.
But I cannot see when it uses 'TLSv1.2' to connect to the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

[Mail.dll](https://www.limilabs.com/mail) doesn't use `ServicePointManager` to select SSL/TLS protocol versions.

To force specific protocol use client's `SSLConfiguration` property:

```
client.SSLConfiguration.EnabledSslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12
```

For IMAP your code should look like this:

```
using (Imap client = new Imap())
{
    // client.SSLConfiguration.EnabledSslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12;
    client.ConnectSSL("outlook.office365.com");
    client.LoginOAUTH2(userName, accessToken);

    client.SelectInbox();

    List<long> uids = client.GetAll();

    client.Close();
}
```

For SMTP (Office365 requires explicit TLS/SSL - StartTLS method after Connect):

```
using (Smtp client = new Smtp())
{
    // client.SSLConfiguration.EnabledSslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12;
    client.Connect("outlook.office365.com");
    client.StartTLS();

    client.LoginOAUTH2(userName, accessToken);

    // ...

    client.Close();
}
```